# C# Comparing user input into array of string

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm comparing user input into my 2d array which is the codes below

```
string[,] Arr = new string[,]{
{"A1" , " A2" , " A3" , " A4" , " A5"},
{"B1" , " B2" , " B3" , " B4" , " B5"}};
```

im using this codes to compare

```
bool invalid = Enumerable.SequenceEqual(UserInput, Arr);
```

i want to output invalid if the user entered an string which is not in the array

Comment: What is the type `UserInput`?

Comment: i want to output invalid if the user inputs an integer or a string which is not in my 2d array

Comment: i got a ArgumentNullException and InvalidOperationException

Comment: Did you understand my comment? I ask what is the type of `UserInput` variable. If it is string, you can: `Arr.OfType<string>().Contains(UserInput);`.

Answer (score 2):

While LINQ may make the code look "clean", you have to understand that it still has to examine each element of the array in order to determine whether or not the requested item is present.

How it accomplishes this internally may or may not be more efficient than you can code by hand. In fact, I have seen many cases where programmers make their applications much more inefficient by converting existing code to LINQ simply because it is "cleaner".

For example, asking LINQ to collect a list of items that meet a specific criteria, then looping through the resultset is much more inefficient than a straight loop: if the item you are looking for is in the last position of the list, you could loop through the list twice using LINQ and then iterating the items rather than a single time with a straight loop.

Now to apply the above information to your specific problem, the real question is what you are trying to do when the match is made? If you are trying to locate the position in the array of the entry, then there is one approach. If you are trying just to validate the entry, then there is a different approach.

If this were my application, the arrays were not large, and I was just interested in validating the existence of the item in the array, I would load the array into a case/culture-insensitive [Hashset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then use the [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to determine if the user's input was valid. The primary reason for this approach is that the Contains method has O(1) performance.

If the user input is obtained in a loop, add the following before the loop:

```
    var cItems = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    foreach (var sValue in Arr)
    {
        cItems.Add(sValue);
    }
```

Then, within the loop, add this to test the existence of the user input:

```
    if (!cItems.Contains(UserInput))
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Invalid Entry");
    }
```

This will be efficient if you are asking for a lot of input because you only have to convert the array once.

If, in the future, you want to find the X/Y coordinate of the entered item, then there would be different approaches, depending on the amount of data in the array and how much input you are expecting from the user.

Answer (score 1):

Just accept string using String input = Console.ReadLine();
Then use foreach on your array and compare it with the input.

Use this, its long though:

```
        bool c =false;
        string[,] Arr = new string[,]{
            {"A1" , "A2" , "A3" , "A4" , "A5"},
            {"B1" , "B2" , "B3" , "B4" , "B5"}};
        Console.Write("Input: ");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        foreach (String temp in Arr)
        {
            c = input.Equals(temp);
            if (c)
                break;
        }

        if (c)
            Console.Write("Your input is on the array.");
        else
            Console.Write("Your input is not on the array.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> i want to output invalid if the user entered an string which is not in
>   the array

In order to comparing two arrays in this way, you have to flatten your 2D Array "Arr" into 1D Array with [Enumerable.SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx). Then use [Enumerable.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx) on UserInput with [Enumerable.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains(v=vs.100).ASPX) on the flatten array with Linq query.

UserInput must be an array too !

Example :

```
var flattenArr = Arr.SelectMany(x=>x).ToArray();
bool invalid = UserInput.Any(x => !flattenArr.Contains(x));
```

If any element of UserInput is not contained by "flattenArr" it return true.

Not forget to using System.Linq.